# How to add items from a foreach loop into a string with json_encode() in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, foreach

I'm trying to insert into a string all emails retrieved from the database, so I can use javascript to check if the email typed by the user into a form field is already registered. I'm trying to use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
    $conectar = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);
    $listarCorreos = " SELECT userEmail 
                       FROM usuarios 
                    ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar,$listarCorreos);

    $arrayEmails = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

foreach($arrayEmails as $row){
    $emails[]=array($row['userEmail']);
}
echo json_encode($emails);
```

Now, I'm getting this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'userEmail' in /home/verificarEmail.php
>   on line 21

Line 21 is `$emails[]=array($row['userEmail']);`

What Am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE:

I'm also trying:

```
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar,$listarCorreos);

$emails = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
  $emails[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emails);
```

And I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   object given in /home/verificarEmail.php on line 18

Line 18: `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {`

Comment: Not an assoc result? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` like below

```
$conectar = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);
    $listarCorreos = " SELECT userEmail 
                       FROM usuarios 
                    ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar,$listarCorreos);    

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
      $emails[]=array($row['userEmail']);    
    }
echo json_encode($emails);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems there.  To get your emails in an array do:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conectar,$listarCorreos);
if(!resultado) die($mysqli_error($conectar));//check for errors

$emails = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado);//fetch all results
echo json_encode($emails);
```

That should get your code working or show you the error. However, **please don't do this**.

> so I can use javascript to check if the email typed by the user into a
>   form field is already registered

This is a *terrible* idea security wise because it will expose all your users' emails to people who are not even registered to your site.  You should instead look up the desired username in the DB directly. If it's not there, then it hasn't been registered before. The Javascript side should only get a `available` or `not available` response.

The process (pseudo-code):

1. `SELECT userEmail from usarios WHERE userEmail = ?`  ? is email to look for
2. execute query and capture `$resultado`
3. If `$resultado` is false, `die(mysqli_error($conectar))` to show error
4. if `mysqli_num_rows($resultado) === 0` email is `available`; else `not available`
5. Echo `available` or `not available` to Javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
use the code like below


$conectar = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);
     $listarCorreos = " SELECT userEmail 
                       FROM usuarios 
                    ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar,$listarCorreos);    

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado) ) {
      $emails[]=$row['userEmail'];    
    }
echo json_encode($emails);
```

Answer (score -1):

use the code like below
$conectar = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);
     $listarCorreos = " SELECT userEmail 
                       FROM usuarios 
                    ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar,$listarCorreos);

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado) ) {
  $emails[]=$row['userEmail '];    
}
```

echo json_encode($emails);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Ashok.  Please don't leave unfinished answers to go type up new ones.  You can just edit an answer you previously posted to fix it.